# overlapping plot with emmeans

Tags: r, plot, overlap, emmeans

I have the following emmeans tables:

```
emm_1
$emmeans
 Order rate   SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 1    19.3 1.51 Inf      16.5      22.5
 2    26.0 2.33 Inf      21.8      31.0

emm_2
$emmeans
 Order rate   SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 1    25.6 1.62 Inf      22.6      28.9
 2    18.8 2.34 Inf      14.8      24.0
```

And I'm trying to plot them both together in the same plot:

```
plot(emm_1,col="steelblue4") + theme_bw() +
  labs(title = "Choice1", 
       x = "Estimated marginal mean",
       y = "Order") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 33,5), limits =c(0,33))
par(new=TRUE)
plot(emm_2,col="green") + theme_bw() +
  labs(title = "Choice2", 
       x = "Estimated marginal mean",
       y = "Order") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 33,5), limits =c(0,33))
```

This runs, although only the second plot is plotted. Is it possible to do this? What do I need to fix?

Comment: You can use `par(mfrow=c(1,2))` to display two graphs side by side.

Comment: My problem is that I want to display the data within the same plot, and I'm not managing to do it

Comment: Oh okay. Then, what I would do is `emm_1$group <- A`, `emm_2$group <- B`, `rbind(emm_1, emm_2)` and rerun the plot with groups.

Comment: Thank you, but in your example, what are supposed to be A, B and group?

Comment: Just random values so that you know in which original data set the values comes from after you bind the rows. Btw, add "" for A and B.